# Creating Noncontinuous Scroll Boxes and Measuring Time in Each Section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a two-part question on creating scroll boxes to be used in a Qualtrics survey and measuring the amount of time people spend looking at the different sections of text within a scroll box.

I'm looking to create a scroll box that contains two paragraphs, where only one paragraph is visible at a time (not continuous scrolling), that can be used in a Qualtrics survey. I've found some html guides for creating scroll boxes (https://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_scroll_box.cfm) but they all seem to only show continuous scrolling.

I also need a way to measure the total amount of time that each paragraph was visible on the screen (If the reader flips back and forth between the two paragraphs, I need to capture the full amount of time that each paragraph was onscreen). Again, I've found resources on how to measure the amount of scrolling (http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/detect-user-scroll-amount.shtml), but not the amount of time within the different sections within the scroll box.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post the code that you have so far and ask a specific question about a problem that you are having with that code. Stack Overflow is about specific programming issues.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you will determine when a user enters or exits a scroll box, but one way to measure the time in each scroll box is to use something like the method below:

```
var scrollBox1Time = 0;
var scrollBox2Time = 0;
//When user enters scroll box 1
var startTime = new Date().getTime();

//When user exits scroll box 1
var endTime = new Date().getTime();
scrollBox1Time += (endTime-startTime);

//When user enters scroll box 2
var startTime = new Date().getTime();

//When user exits scroll box 2
var endTime = new Date().getTime();
scrollBox2Time += (endTime-startTime);  //Add time for scroll box 2
```

The time is measured in milliseconds.